# Android Calendar.compareTo returns 0 for different times

Tags: java, android

I found a strange behavior of `Calendar` class in Android. When I need to sort some list of events by time, I construct a `Comparator` like this:

```
    @Override
    public int compare(Event lhs, Event rhs) {
        return lhs.getUserTime().compareTo(rhs.getUserTime());
    }
```

where `getUserTime` is a `Calendar` instance. The strange thing is that this method always returns 0 even if `Dates` wrapped in `Calendars` are explicitly different.

Extracting `Dates` from `Calendars` solves the problem:

```
    @Override
    public int compare(Event lhs, Event rhs) {
        return lhs.getUserTime().getTime().compareTo(rhs.getUserTime().getTime());
    }
```

But I don't understand where the problem comes from in the first place.

Comment: Considered stepping through the Calendar.compareTo method?

Comment: The original code compares Calendar object to long value (or whatever getTime returns), should have thrown an exception.

Comment: Sorry, of course it compares Calendar to Calendar.